# Order saving error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'customer_id' cannot be null,

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

order from backend to my customer. i am getting below message

Order saving error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'customer_id' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `rewardpointspro_account` (`customer_id`, `store_id`, `points_current`, `points_received`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

Can any one help me resolving the same as i m new in magento

Comment: I want to place order from backend on behalf of my customer

Comment: Hopefully for such exception we would have some logs generated in magento exception log (var/log/exception.log) or in Server php error.log file.Probably there may be some extension which is overriding the existing behavior in magento due to which we are getting this sql error hopefully from logs we will be able to identify the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that "rewardpointspro" extension may be broken.  Magento is attempting to write a record in a database where one of the values (customer_id) which should not be null is set to null.

I'd reach out to the developer of that plugin for assistance unless you want to dig into (and fix) his code.